# Is there a way to "set" Hadoop Counter instead of incrementing it?

Tags: hadoop

API only provides methods to increase a counter in Mapper or Reducer. Is there a way to just set it? or increment it's value only once irrespective of the number of times mappers and reducers are run.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? This is inherently tricky, as what if multiple mappers try to set the counter? Who should win? The reason counters typically are only incremented is that this can be done very, very quickly and efficiently by the architecture.

Comment: Basic purpose is to associate a piece of information with a Job run.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the counter because the counters are summed from each of the tasks and aggregated into a top-level counter.

I have used [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) within MapReduce jobs for small communications or coordinations between tasks or flagging certain things that happened in a job or task.

Comment: True, the counter can't be reset by using the Hadoop API at least.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done from the Hadoop API at least as pointed out by @orangeoctupus as well.
The approach I used for achieve this was to set the value in Job's Context properties. In the end the properties can be read after the job is run. Non-elegant but a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

The interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter [defines a method setValue](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html#setValue%28long%29), but if it works globally like it seems to based upon the description, I would agree with other answers that there aren't many use cases for it that are also good ideas...